# Silverlight looking at wrong url for clientaccesspolicy file

Tags: wcf, configuration, silverlight-3.0

i have a silverlight app connected to a webservice over https.

The webservice is hosted on mydomain.com (not localhost).

When i run the silverlight, it makes https calls to webservice on mydomain.com, but also tries to access "http://localhost/clientaccesspolicy.xml" and fails obviously. Why is my SL app looking for cal.xml in localhost? why is it not looking for cal.xml in the mydomain.com?

Appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: what address is the SL3 application hosted on in IIS(or are u running it in vs), and what address is the Webservice hosted (assuming from ur post its https://mydomain.com?)

Comment: @Neil: SL3 hosted on https://mydomain.com
Ws hosted on https://mydomain.com/ws/service.svc

Answer (score 0):

*"Before allowing a connection to a network resource, the Silverlight runtime will try to download a security policy file from the domain that hosts the network resource. There are two different methods used to download the security policy that depend on whether the connection request was from a WebClient or HTTP class or whether the connection request was from sockets.
If the connection request was from a WebClient or an HTTP class to a cross-domain site, the Silverlight runtime tries to download the security policy file using the HTTP protocol. The Silverlight runtime first tries to download a Silverlight policy file with a name of "clientaccesspolicy.xml" at the root of the requested target domain using the HTTP protocol.
If the "clientaccesspolicy.xml" is either not found (the web request returns a 404 status code), returned with an unexpected mime-type, is not valid XML, or has an invalid root node, then the Silverlight runtime will issue a request for a for the Flash policy file with a name of "crossdomain.xml" at the root of the requested target domain, using the HTTP protocol."*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What does the address look like inside your SL application?
Is the address coming from the ServiceReference.ClientConfig file? If so, make sure that it has a mydomain.com and not a localhost address there.